# Setting up multiple tables on single form with overlapping fields?

Tags: forms, ms-access

So I have three tables (I had to split up what would be one table into three because it was apparently over the 255 rows limit) that I would like to be connected to a single form.

Each table has the participant ID# as well as the date and data enterer's initials.  However, those three fields will be the same across each table as each table is 1/3 of a single questionnaire.  How would I go about creating a single form for all three of these tables given that I have these fields?

If I am not being specific enough please let me know and I will try to rephrase.

Thanks!

Comment: Over the 255 **rows limit** ?

Comment: Fields limit, I suppose.